# How to show next slide with bootstrap carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have checked my carousel image attributes if they undefined or empty and then show next slide but  I have a bit of a bug I couldn't fix it so I need some help.

I want to tell you my scenario:

> on desktop (large screen) if  my `data-large` is empty or undefined
>   then show next slide
>
> on tablet (medium screen) if my `data-medium` is empty or undefined
>   then show next slide
>
> on mobile (small screen) if my `data-small` is empty or undefined then
>   show next slide.

and check attribute with next/prev button of my carousel

I try to do something so for but it's not working properly.

so I guess my `controlImages()` function is not coded correctly.

```js
! function(e) {
  e.fn.imageR = function(a) {
    function i(e, i, r, u, n) {
      $mediaQuery < a.large ? $mediaQuery < a.medium ? $mediaQuery < a.small || (n ? e.attr("src", i) : e.css("background-image", "url(" + i + ")")) : n ? e.attr("src", r) : e.css("background-image", "url(" + r + ")") : n ? e.attr("src", u) : e.css("background-image", "url(" + u + ")")
    }

    function r() {
      $imageR.each(function() {
        var e = jQuery(this),
          a = e.data("small"),
          r = e.data("medium"),
          u = e.data("large"),
          n = !1;
        (void 0 === r || null === r) && (r = u), (void 0 === a || null === a) && (a = r), e.is("img") && (n = !0), i(e, a, r, u, n)
      })
    }
    var u = {
      small: "0",
      medium: "480",
      large: "1024"
    };
    a = e.extend(u, a), $imageR = jQuery(this), $mediaQuery = jQuery(window).width(), r(), jQuery(window).on("resize", function() {
      $mediaQuery = jQuery(window).width(), r()
    })
  }
}(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lazy_banner').imageR();
});



$(function() {
  $('.lazy_banner').each(function(e) {
    var
      ElDesktop = $(this).data('large'),
      ElTablet = $(this).data('medium'),
      ElMobil = $(this).data('small');


    function controlImages() {
      if ($(window).width() >= 980) {
        if (ElDesktop == "" || ElDesktop == undefined) {
          $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
        }
      } else if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        if (ElTablet == "" || ElTablet == undefined) {
          $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
        }
      } else if ($(window).width() < 480) {
        if (ElMobil == "" || ElMobil == undefined) {
          $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
        }
      }
    }
    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
      controlImages();
    });
  });

});
```

```css
img {
  height: 300px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img class="lazy_banner" data-large="https://image.ibb.co/dh3MSk/desktop_1.jpg" data-medium="" data-small="https://image.ibb.co/bVYc05/mobil.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="lazy_banner" data-large="https://images.pexels.com/photos/40797/wild-flowers-flowers-plant-macro-40797.jpeg" data-medium="https://images.pexels.com/photos/30865/pexels-photo-30865.jpg" data-small="https://images.pexels.com/photos/122429/leaf-nature-green-spring-122429.jpeg">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img class="lazy_banner" data-large="" data-medium="https://www.jssor.com/demos/img/gallery/980x380/013.jpg" data-small="https://www.jssor.com/demos/img/gallery/980x380/015.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/dRZbVm)

Comment: Right now you have it working on "load" and "resize" and thats it. You need to tie it everytime the image changes

Comment: so what do I have to change ? how should it be my code ? thanks @Keith

Answer (score 0):

Alright my friend, it took a bit but I figured it out for you:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLeLOg

```
  $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(){
     var  ElDesktop = $(this).find('.active img').attr('data-large'),
          ElTablet = $(this).find('.active img').attr('data-medium'),
          ElMobil = $(this).find('.active img').attr('data-small');

     if(ElDesktop == '' || ElTablet == '' || ElMobil == ''){
       $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
     }
  })
```

There is a bootstrap indicator ( slid.bs.carousel ) which is on slide and a ( slide.bs.carousel ) when it is finished. Just add that script at the end and it should work. Also, you were selecting (this), which is the div and not the image in which has the attribute.

Comment: no there is something you didn't understand my image is chancing on responsive if you resize the window you will see.and I have more than one image and I guess I need to do with each function and this condition can be wrong because if resulution of my windows less than 980px (for tablet) and if my data-medium is empty or undefined then slide next image so what if my data-medium is not empty ? then it will show next image too because you condition says: if data-large empty too then next sorry about my english

Comment: the resizing part I guess doesn't, but on load that script works

Comment: but it doesn't work properly if you check it out.for example open this carousel on tablet size (860px): https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/QgaaXV you will see image will be empty it doesn't show next slide

Comment: and on tablet if you click next button it slide two times